# Professional work history - is it taboo to list on my consultancy website?

Tags: portfolio

I am developing a website for my software development / consulting business. Is it appropriate to have a section "Resume" or "About Me" that lists my non-freelancing job experience? I have seen many freelancers craft a personal site and a freelance/professional site, and they would put their "seeking-full-time-job" style resume in the Personal site, and put their portfolio and freelance projects on their business/professional website. This seems like overkill - but on the other hand, I do not want someone to see my resume on my consultancy site and interpret this somehow as unprofessional.

Much of my work experience helps demonstrate my technical skill, but not necessarily my skill as a consultant. **Whether I am selling consulting or selling my butt planted in a cubicle chair 9-5, I would think it is appropriate to list my work history - but I seldom see this on freelancer's portfolio sites so I'm questioning my instincts. Should I avoid resume-style work history list on a professional/consulting website? I'm simply worried it will come off as unprofessional.** For what it is worth,  the business is a one man operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the information, but not in a "resume" or "CV" style....

Rather than:

- 2005-2008 Company X
  Director of XXX
  Responsible for XXX, XXXX, and XXXX

Use something like:

- 3 years developing software designed to XXXXX
  Included debugging and deployment on XXXX and XXXX platforms

That sort of thing.

You don't have to throw away the information if you feel it's valuable, and you shouldn't fabricate anything. However, you can merely present the information in a different manner showing *what you did* rather than "where you worked" and focusing more on experience than career path.

And presenting it in a non-resume type format will immediately overcome the impression that the experience was all on-the-job. So, readers won't know right away when you started consulting as opposed to being a full time employee somewhere.

Comment: I like the advice, it could work well for me. But could this be  considered misleading in some way? Or does it not matter, if I am providing those services anyway?

Comment: No, use valid information, just leave off company names and dates, that's all. If asked, state it was employment, but you don't necessarily need to disclose that on the web site.